# Sharing internet with a ethernet cable

Tags: internet, ethernet, connection-sharing

I have a laptop and a desktop computer, both with Ubuntu 22.04 installed. I wanted to share the internet from the laptop which is connected to wifi to the desktop using an ethernet cable. I then connected the ethernet cable and set ipv4 and ipv6 methods to 'Share to other computers'. Now the wired connection says 'connected' in both computers. But I still cannot get the desktop computer to access the internet. Please note that I don't have another way to connect the desktop computer to the internet so tools like net-tools are not installed in the desktop.
Could you please advise me on how I can get this desktop access to the internet through my laptop?

Thank you in advance.
AN

Comment: See this link: [How to configure ubuntu as a router](https://www.opensourceforu.com/2015/04/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-a-router/)

Comment: having a wifi available the best solution is buying a wifi-usb-adapter and install it into the desktop, so that you can access the wifi directly from both machines, avoiding the use of cables and relevant SW complications.

Comment: Thanks, @precise and ClaudioKlaus. Yeah, I want to connect this computer to the internet to get the drivers for the wifi adapter. All good.
Thanks for your responses.